# How to close system dialog or notification on OS version 7.0+?

Tags: android

I am developing android app and i want close system dialog programmatically.
I am using this code for closing system dialog, this code is working fine in android 6.0 and below versions but the problem is that it's not working in android 7.0 and android 8.0. How to solve this problem.
Please help me thanks advance.

```
Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to close notification panel,

I am using below code for android Oreo.

```
Handler collapseNotificationHandler;

@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        Log.d(tag, "window focus changed");

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            collapseNow();
        }
    }


public void collapseNow() {

        try {
            // Initialize 'collapseNotificationHandler'
            if (collapseNotificationHandler == null) {
                collapseNotificationHandler = new Handler();
            }

            // Post a Runnable with some delay - currently set to 300 ms
            collapseNotificationHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    // Use reflection to trigger a method from 'StatusBarManager'
                    Object statusBarService = getSystemService("statusbar");
                    Class<?> statusBarManager = null;

                    try {
                        statusBarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Method collapseStatusBar = null;
                    try {
                        // Prior to API 17, the method to call is 'collapse()'
                        // API 17 onwards, the method to call is `collapsePanels()`

                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
                            collapseStatusBar = statusBarManager.getMethod("collapsePanels");
                        } else {
                            collapseStatusBar = statusBarManager.getMethod("collapse");
                        }
                    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    collapseStatusBar.setAccessible(true);

                    try {
                        collapseStatusBar.invoke(statusBarService);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // Currently, the delay is 10 ms. You can change this
                    // value to suit your needs.
                    collapseNotificationHandler.postDelayed(this, 10L);
                }
            }, 10L);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks @chirag Savsani this code working only in android 8.0 but not working in android 7.0.

Comment: Remove `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)` this condition and try.

Comment: please help me.

Comment: Thanks @chirag savsani.